# How to accelerate MySQL count query or let it run in background

Tags: mysql, count, background-process

I have a table that has around 3 million rows. The table is like this:

```
director_id movie_id
----------- --------
1           5
1           9
1           11
3           7
3           15
```

I need movie_count per director. Doing this for a single director took about 800 ms in a SELECT statement from the MySQL client. I am iterating through main director table, taking director.id and with it querying this table for the count. It takes forever with 3 million of records.

**Important**

Please note that a director can have over 2000 movies. Not just 3 or 5.

Code is like that:

```
public function movieCount($director_id)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(`director_id`) `movie_count` FROM `movie_director`
                WHERE `director_id` = "' .$director_id .'"';

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $row;
}


public function directors(): iterable
{
    $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `directors`';

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        yield $row;
    }
}


foreach($directors as $director) {
    $movieCount = movieCount($director["id"]);

    // Write movieCount to somewhere
}
```

**Question is:**

Is there any way to make this more efficient? I think it would be best if movie_count was written to director table beforehand so i can quickly select it. Is there a way to automatise this so, when idle MySQL engine query it slowly and write it to the director table in movie_count in background?

Comment: share what is output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`? You just need 1-2 indexes

Comment: Have you tried looking at the execution plan of your query to see if an index is missing? Writing data back to the rows while it could get calculated in real time is not a good idea

Comment: Why not simply `join` with `group by` on director id. Show us all relevant tables and expected output

Comment: You mention `I am iterating through` are you not using mysql to `select` things?

Comment: @Mark lol, I'll save this post to share if you are right. But I don't think it is that bad :-)

Comment: @Alex I have UNIQUE KEY `director_id` (`movie_id`,`director_id`). Do you think other indexing will help?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you're using to `iterate`? Or the code that's taking `800ms` to execute?

Comment: @NicoHaase No I don't want to write in real time. I just need some that data to transfer to another DB from time to time(like a cronjob). But in its current situation it just took so long maybe I thought preparing them before will help for transferring now since count field will be ready.

Comment: @Mark it is just plain MySQL query from a MySQL client. That 800 ms. (but i will iterate them in PHP using PDO) Now that example i gave above is a very small example. Like a director can have over 2000 movies.

Comment: Simply do this: `select director_id, count(*) as total_movies from tablename group by director_id`

Comment: So you're using `select * from my_table` and then iterating over that using PHP? Can you still include the code? It's hard to see what's taking long if there's no code.

Comment: I think I've asked you to share your schema, and I would ask you to provide the query you use. And since you are using php,. share your code fragment.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya That is nice but i need to do that while I am at that "director_id".

Comment: @Mark Meaning I am selecting some fields from "director" table and then i am "foreach"ing that collection. In that loop i am taking the id of director and query this table to know to movie count

Comment: Please: don't tell us what you do, share the code you use!

Comment: Two ways: 1. When you are fetching some data from director table, you can do a join with movies table at that time and group by on director id to get fields + count
2. Another way is collect all director id(s) in a single string, and use `IN()` clause and get count for all the directors in a single query itself

Comment: @Alex updated with code

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya First one is taking too long but second one seems nice!

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya but maybe with indexing join will be much much faster. So i can also take counts when selecting directors table.

Comment: @somethingyouwant yes that is why I suggested it as Way 1

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya getting "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column ‘directors.id’ which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Ok found it i am first selecting from "directors" table but GROUP BY from 'movie_director'. 'director_id'.  That doesn't work. Instead GROUP BY "id" works.

Answer (score 3):

Add index to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE movie_director ADD INDEX accelerate (director_id);
```

And then you can run select query for particular `director_id`:

```
SELECT director_id, 
       count(*) as total_movies 
FROM movie_director
WHERE director_id = 123
```

If you care more about performance you need to get rid of this loop:

```
foreach($directors as $director) {
    $movieCount = movieCount($director["id"]);
    ...
}
```

And to get all counts in one shot with `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT director_id, 
       count(*) as total_movies 
FROM movie_director
GROUP BY director_id;
```

To apply this change to your code you can modify your function:

```
public function movieCounts()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) `movie_count` 
            FROM `movie_director`
            GROUP BY `director_id`';
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
}
$counts = movieCounts();
foreach($directors as $director) {
    $movieCount = $counts[$director['id']] ?? 0;

    // Write movieCount to somewhere
}
```

Comment: After the index that query accelerated immensely. Now the movieCounts function can be removed and it can be done on Directors function via JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of querying for a single director_id in loop, you can "collect" all the director_id(s) at once, and then use a single query.

```
public function movieCountForDirectors($director_ids)
{
    $sql = "SELECT `director_id`, 
                    COUNT(*) `movie_count` 
             FROM `movie_director`
             WHERE `director_id` IN (" .$director_ids . ") 
             GROUP BY `director_id`";

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $rows;
}


public function directors(): iterable
{
    $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `directors`';

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        yield $row;
    }
}

// Get all director id(s) in comma separated string
$director_ids = implode(',', array_column($directors, 'id'));

// get movie counts for all of them
$counts = movieCountForDirectors($director_ids);
```